# VB.Net Web Browser control - how do you handle popups?

Tags: vb.net, popup, webbrowser-control

I have a large project in Vb.net which drives a web browser control around. What's the best, and easiest, way to manage browser pop ups? Note, I am not just looking to cancel or close them. I need to manage them just like the main window.

Comment: have you check ajax modal popup available for asp.net?

Comment: do you want to display popup in your own window or you want to have the yellow secure bar to allow popups?

Comment: display it in my own window...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [NewWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768335(v=vs.85).aspx)/[NewWindow2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768336(v=vs.85).aspx)/[NewWindow3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768337(v=vs.85).aspx) events:

Comment: This worked with the extended browser control. This worked... thanks.